# How to find wide characters from the given input string?

Tags: c#

How to find wide characters from the given input string(English letters)?

I have a business requirement  to get last name(English letters) with max length of 12 by  considering wide character( length  2) and normal character ( length  1). Based on that, input box should accept  number of characters.

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, please don't prefix your titles with things like "C#:". That's what tags are for.

Comment: Obligatory http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Because there seems to be some confusion, I'll repost a comment I made on a post that's now deleted: "Double width characters" usually refer to (mostly CJK) characters that are two "normal" characters wide (give or take depending on the renderer) when rendering in monospace. For instance: `AABBCCあ漢字`

Comment: Wide characters can also refer to any character in an encoding that consumes more than 1 byte. It's impossible to know if the poster is talking about screen width or data width.

Comment: More guesses unless Vidya comments... Maybe "wide" characters from "English letters" are 'W','M' as opposed to narrow 'I' and 'J'?

Comment: I still have no idea what this question is asking...

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**:

If you are talking about asian characters (like Japanese 全角) then here is one way.

```
    public static bool isZenkaku(string str)
    {
        int num = sjisEnc.GetByteCount(str);
        return num == str.Length * 2;
    }
```

You would use it like this:

```
        string test = "testＴＥＳＴ！＋亜+123!１２３";
        var widechars = test.Where(c => isZenkaku(c.ToString())).ToList();
        foreach (var c in widechars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c); //result is ＴＥＳＴ！＋亜１２３

        }
```

Comment: What if a character doesn't have a wide version? Few non-CJK characters do.

Comment: That's a good point. i added a note about the exception it would throw.

Comment: Updated my answer to be clear what my undestanding of the question was.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking into this a while ago and the String class's Length property tells you the number of characters not the number of bytes.  You can do something where when the Length of the string is greater then 12 return the left 12 characters.  There could be anything up to 24 bytes in the string.

Comment: -1: "looking into this" - unlikely to be useful for such unclear question. Up to X bytes in a string without specifying encoding makes not much sense. If you talking about amount of bytes used by String object itself it is again unlikely to be useful for original poster, and 2 * String.Length is just rough estimation of such value.

Comment: When a string contains any unicode characters, all characters in the string are stored in unicode.  When a character is not a wide character then the first byte of the two bytes is always a zero.  The way the question read to me was that he wanted a text box to be able to accept up to 12 characters for a last name and the box can take both normal and wide characters.